# write a long int as it is by df.to_csv()

Tags: python

I am converting a list of Alphanumerics to hexadecimal values like the following:

```
for j in range(i.item_quantity):
    it = str(i.item.short_code)+"R1"+"T"+yr[2:]+ str(grn.pk) + str(j+1).zfill(2)
    it = str.encode(it)
    h = codecs.encode(it, "hex")
    print("h", h.decode("utf-8"))
    items.append(h.decode("utf-8"))
    item_type.append(i.item.description)
```

while it prints

```
h 50505231543232343739313937
h 50505231543232343739313938
```

when I convert this to a dataframe and further to csv file the output is like the following:

[image]

How can I convert them such that the complete value is shown in the csv?

Comment: the final blank image is NOT a csv, but a CSV loaded as a sheet in a tool like excel. A csvfile is a TEXT file. So open the CSV with notepad to ensure the format is OK. Then it is onlya  matter of configuration to display it in scientific style or not in the excel or like tool

Comment: Both of them are actually the same value. However, you can bypass the sciencetific notation by formatting it:  `f'{h:.23f}'`